# Let $R$ be any ring. Prove that the following equations must hold in $R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

By letting $R$ be any ring I have to show these following equations hold in $R$:

a) $x\cdot 0=0$

b) $0\cdot x=0$

c) $-(-x)=x$

d) $(-x)\cdot(-y)=x\cdot y$

I'm not really looking for the answer just for a hint to get me started. I guess I'm confused on how to show these properties hold within $R$.

Answer (score 3):

1. $x \cdot 0 = 0$: Observe that $x \cdot 0 = x \cdot (0 + 0) = x \cdot 0 + x \cdot 0$ Hence we have $x \cdot 0 = x \cdot 0 + x \cdot 0$. If we subtract $x \cdot 0$ from both sides, we get $0 = x \cdot 0$.
2. $0 \cdot x = 0$: Similar reasoning.
3. $-(-x) = x$: Observe that since $R$ is a ring, it is an additive group, so elements have additive inverses. Thus for all $x \in R$, $x + (-x) = 0$. Subtract $(-x)$ from both sides and get $x = -(-x)$.
4. $(-x)(-y) = xy$: Before we show this, observe that $a(-b) = (-a)b = -ab$. Now observe that $0 = x \cdot 0 = x(y + (-y)) = xy + x \cdot(-y)$. Subtracting $x\cdot (-y)$ from both sides yields $xy = -x(-y) = (-x)(-y)$.

**Why** does $a(-b) = (-a)b = -ab$? Well observe that $0 = a \cdot 0 = a(b + (-b)) = ab + a(-b)$ which implies $a(-b) = -ab$. Similarly $0 = 0 \cdot b = (a + (-a))b = ab + (-a)b$ which implies $(-a)b = -ab$. Hence $a(-b) = (-a)b = -ab$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint : $-1$ is the additive inverse of $1$ and $-1$ is the multiplicative inverse of $-1$.

$$ 1 -1 = 0$$ $$(-1)\times (-1) = 1$$

Then use distributivity.

Comment: So proving all the above this is what I've got for my proof:

Comment: We know the (1-1)=0 ==> x*0=0 ==> x*(1-1)=0 ==> x-x=0 ==> 0=0

Comment: Sorry I pressed enter by accident. But continuing 0*x is the same as the first method but the only reason you have to prove this is because multiplication is some cases is not commutative. For part c, since (-1)*(-1)=1 ==> -(-x)=x ==> (-1)*(-1)*x=x ==> x=x. Finally for the last part, since (-1)(-1)=1 ==> (-x)*(-y)=x*y ==> (-1)*(x)*(-1)*(y)=x*y ==> (-1*-1)*(x*y)=x*y ==> x*y=x*y. Therefore all the equations hold in R.

Comment: First of all, what if the ring doesn't have a $1$? Like, the ring of all even integers? Second, if the ring does have a $1$, you have to prove $(-1)(-1)=1$. Third, proving $(x)(0)=0$ implies $0=0$ doesn't prove $(x)(0)=0$. I think there is still a lot of work to do.

Comment: You said it was a ring, not a non-unital ring.

Comment: Damien, if you are addressing me, you should write @Gerry to ensure I see your comment. I don't know which definition of ring OP is using --- perhaps we'll get some clarification. But my other points stand, regardless.

Comment: @DamienL One needs to be precise at this level. Does the minus symbol in $\,1 - 1\,$ denote a binary ring operation, or is it the unary inverse operation in the additive group? One of the main points of the exercise is to *rigorously* clarify how the two are related, so one cannot gloss over that.